# How to create a relational expression(=equation) from a complex parameter?

Tags: equation-solving, eliminate

I obtained the following parameters in the process of solving a problem.

```
eq1 = x == -3 + 9 c + 12 c^2 - 8 c^4; 
eq2 = y^2 == 81 - 81 c^2 - 144 c^3 + 144 c^5 + 64 c^6 - 64 c^8;
```

Now I want to remove c from the two expressions, and get a relational expression of x and y. The results for the relationship I want are as follows.

```
16 (x^2 - 3 y^2)^3 + 7950960 (x^2 + y^2) + 48 (x^2 - 3 y^2)^2 (x^2 + y^2) - 41283 (x^2 + y^2)^2 - 45 (x^2 + y^2)^3 + (x^2 + y^2)^4 + x (x^2 - 3 y^2) (266382 - 5544 (x^2 + y^2) + 16 (x^2 + y^2)^2) == 373248000
```

In order to obtain the above results, I executed the following commands. However, after an hour, no results are available.

```
Eliminate[{eq1, eq2}, c]
```

What other methods can I use to get the above results?

Comment: in V 13.3.1 the Eliminate command finishes in 0.0001 seconds.  Try from clean kernel?

Comment: I am 13.2. I'll do it with 13.3!!

Comment: Thank you, I'm upgrading the version to 13.3 so it works well!!

Comment: There does appear to be a problem with this calculation with either v13.2 or v13.2.1 on a Mac

Comment: The calculation did not complete on V12.2.0 on Win7-x64 in reasonable time, so I had to stop it.

Comment: In v13.2, algebraic operations such as Factor[x^255255-1] also have debugs. You can't do the calculation. However, in v13.3, it is calculated quickly.